# Unexpected value X imported by the module Z when using flag --aot

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-mdl

My app is very slow until load finish when running on browser (I dare not speak about mobile uhhhh 10-15seconds) Yes, I do `ng build --prod` and it's still slow.

So with angular cli beta 16 I try the new flag --aot 
And I get a lot of imports and declarations error:

```
 0% compilingUnexpected value 'FileDropDirective' declared by the module 'AppModule'
Error: Unexpected value 'FileDropDirective' declared by the module 'AppModule'
    at C:\Users\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14174:33
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

Then just for fun I comment 3 libs which did me this error, just to see if it will continue to compile... NO ! I get another error:

```
10% building modules 6/12 modules 6 active ...ode_modules\style-loader\addStyles.jsSyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at WebpackResourceLoader._evaluate (C:\Users\...\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\resource_loader.js:75:24)
```

How achieve? thanks

Comment: Can you show us some source code please ? Your AppModule and FileDropDirective ;)

Comment: here you are: http://pastebin.com/fxAUmDBF

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.0.0 of angular2-mdl hase been released today. AOT is now supported.

Comment: i know. will be fixed with 2.0.1. but the readme content is the same as on giihub.

Comment: BEAUCOUP DE PROBLEMES, I get lot errors after update to 2.0.0! In app.component.ts I use service MdlDialogOutletService and I get `angular2-mdl/components/index"' has no exported member 'MdlDialogOutletService'.` then In my dialog component dialog I have http://pastebin.com/UbJs3Y9U and I get `WARNING in ./src/app/edit-dialog/edit-dialog.component.ts
92:170 export 'MdlDialogReference' was not found in 'angular2-mdl'

WARNING in ./src/app/edit-dialog/edit-dialog.component.ts
92:208 export 'MdlDialogReference' was not found in 'angular2-mdl'
`

Comment: I also have these error: `WARNING in ./src/app/tabs-view/tabs-view.component.ts
305:98 export 'MdlDialogService' was not found in 'angular2-mdl'
`

Comment: So I tried remove this MdlDialogOutletService and put only <dialog-outlet></dialog-outlet> in index.html so I get always error `'MdlDialogService' was not found in 'angular2-mdl'` and 
 `MdlDialogReference' was not found in 'angular2-mdl` 
Je ne comprends pas!

Comment: please read the https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md. the version number increases because of the breaking changes. thats the way semver works.

Comment: I think it's not an problem to get it working but before I import all service from angular2-mdl  but now export not found with MdlDialogService and MdlDialogreference so I need import them from `import {MdlDialogService, MdlDialogReference} from 'angular2-mdl/components/dialog/mdl-dialog.service';`

Does this normal

Comment: you need to import from 'angular2-mdl': import {MdlDialogService, MdlDialogReference} from 'angular2-mdl'

Comment: YES that's what I did ! please check http://i.imgur.com/aNFnmbT.jpg export are failed

Comment: strange. i'm using beta.25 of wepback but this could not be the problem (here is my testproject: https://github.com/fit-4-angular-2/course-menu. can you post the content of the folder npde_modules/angualr2-mdl?

Comment: UDPATE: with cli17 I don't have error !  anyway forget this before !

Comment: @istiti never mind! i know the tooling is sometimes really  a big problem

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `MdlModule` and `Angular2DataTableModule` are some externals libs. If they don't include `*.metadata.json` for each of their Angular files, your AoT compilation cannot know what they do. You can't do much about it, just submit an issue so they update their libs to be compatible with AoT.

But for your `FileDropDirective`, I can't tell without the code.

Comment: How can I resolve it myself until fixed, there is way to achieve? some docs?

Comment: You can clone their project and build it yourself with the proper AoT configuration. Then call `npm pack` to generate a zip version of their lib for NPM. Then in your project, `npm install /path/to/this/zip.tar.gz` to override the public NPM version with your new AoT locale version.

Comment: by example: I tried `npm pack angular2-data-table` I get it then I need edit it no? before install. How and What I need to change to get it AoT-able :) thanks

Comment: You should `git clone` angular2-data-table, edit it, compile and build it with AoT, `npm pack` it, and `npm install` it in your project. For the AoT compilation part, you can start with https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html. You can also look at some other libs that already handle AoT compilation, like https://github.com/noemi-salaun/ng2-logger

Comment: not sure I'm able to get this lib able to be compiled using AoT but will contact team, hope will be enhanced, your logger seems nothing big change https://github.com/noemi-salaun/ng2-logger/commit/a6d5c3f03976b5abe1a48c2d607635de5245245e you only add ` "skipMetadataEmit": false` that's all ?